# Displaying when Button has been pressed for LED and returning 1

Tags: led, button

I've just started using Arduino and I'm having trouble getting my code right.

Here is the task I need to do.

"Create a button read function
  Hint: the function header should be `int checkbutton ( void )`
in the loop function, add code such that if the button has been pressed (i.e. the checkbutton function
returns 1), a message is sent to the serial monitor with your username."

There are no errors in the code but nothing happens in the serial monitor when I press the LED button and it does not return 0 when i don't press the LED button.
Any sort of help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
int Button = 15; //LED and output are on the same pin

int last = 0;  

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int button() {
  pinMode(Button, INPUT); 

  int current = digitalRead(Button); 

  if (current and not last) {       
    delay(5);

    pinMode(Button, OUTPUT);

    Serial.print("Hey");
    return 1;
  }

  else {
    pinMode(Button, OUTPUT);

    current == last;

    return 0;
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (button >=0)
  {
    button();
  }

  else
  {
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look up the StateChangeDetection example that is provided within the Arduino IDE, as well as https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button

Comment: Also, it depends on the microcontroller, but on most arduino products the LED is on pin 13 not 15

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button() function, the line

```
if (current and not last) {
```

is less common syntax. The more common equivalent is:

```
if (current && !last) {
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators)

This line:

```
current == last;
```

Has no effect and is incorrect. This ( “==“ ) is not an assignment but a comparison and does not do what you want it to do.

I also think you have this the wrong way around. You want to save the “last” button state to compare it with the current button state when you call `button()` the next time. So you would need to set “last” to the current button state, like this:

```
last = current;
```

The next time you call `button()`, “last” contains the previous button state, so your comparison to the current button state will work.

And I think your button detection code would work better if you set `last = current` each time you call button(), whether a button has been pressed or not. Otherwise your code would repeatedly keep printing “Hey” until you stop pushing the button (unless that’s what you want). Like so:

```
int button() {
  pinMode(Button, INPUT); 

  int current = digitalRead(Button); 

  if (current &&  !last) {       
    ...
    ...

    Serial.print("Hey");
    last = current; // Insert here
    return 1;
  }

  else {
    pinMode(Button, OUTPUT);
    ...
```

(This has not been tested but should give you a general idea).

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixed my code and helped increase my understanding, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may only be that you are not calling the button function. Try changing `if (button >=0)` to `if (button() >=0)`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I made the change and now the serial monitor is printing hey but its not returning 1, nor am i getting 0 when i do not press the button. Btw, thanks for the edit! Much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to print 0 and 1 to the serial console you'll need to add the Serial.print(...) calls. If I understand what you want correctly, you may be able to replace the entire body of loop() with Serial.println(loop());